# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: unknown on connecting to web service from client

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, axis, wsdl2java

I am running into 'org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: unknown' exceptions when connecting to a web service from client stub. This is an axis 2 web service. Client and server side stubs were generated by using WSDL2Java. I used the below links to embed or integrate my web service into an existing web application.

1. http://wso2.org/library/90
2. http://www.developer.com/services/article.php/3777111/Embedding-Apache-Axis2-into-Existing-Applications.htm

So, I am not using axis 2 admin console. I verified the web service from server side, I was able to view the wsdl and web service is up and running.

I did not see any activity/error/message in the server side log when the exception happens. I am not sure how to debug this further. Any pointers to investigate this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try invoking the same service with SoapUI? Do you get a successful response from SoapUI?

Comment: Thanks Isuru. Wsdl2Code was not generated properly. That was the issue. My operations expects an object type input. I am not sure if SoapUI provides an option to create/instantiate input objects. I will look into it though.

Comment: Hi, you can access the web service from SoapUI when you provide the wsdl. Since you have a WSDL file, you can definitely test from SoapUI